# How do I analyse condensed JavaScript expressions?

Tags: javascript

What does the expression `e = 0 === f ? e : e + a,`  mean?

If it just was

```
0 === f ? e : e + a,
```

I'd know. It means,

if `f` is equals zero (and same type) return `e`, otherwise return `e + a`

but I don't get the first part `e = 0 === f`

Another expression is this: `e + a > c && (d = 0 === f ? d : d + b + this.spacing, e = 0 );`

Here the first part I don't get at all: `e + a > c && (...`

The code I am analysing right now is full of such condensed expressions. What is a good source to learn about those?

Comment: It’s just `e = (0 === f ? e : e + a)`.

Comment: `&&` [returns the first truthy value.](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) (Not just `true` or `false` like in other languages.)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 2):

That's just an assignment. It's assigning the result of the ternary to `e`.

The second one looks like some kind of boundary logic. Look up operator precedence, add explicit parentheses in the equation, and break it down into pieces.

Answer (score 2):

The second is a condition and two assignments, wrapped in parenthesis and a comma operator, which acts as separator, not as operator, because the result is omitted.

```
if (e + a > c) {
    d = 0 === f ? d : d + b + this.spacing;
    e = 0;
}
```